# What is the best way to search text from the Wikipedia dump in java?

Tags: java, full-text-search, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am interested in searching specific sentences containing a pair of words from Wikipedia dump. One approach is to traverse all documents after extracting the dump XML. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Maybe you could try some search engines like lucene.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend inverted index of the content. You could use Lucene, Elastic Search, Solr, etc.

Here is an example using Lucene index: [Wikipedia index using lucene](https://github.com/lemire/IndexWikipedia)